# Internal Server Error - Multiple depth URL string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am currently using this .htaccess file for my website,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^u/([^/]+)/[^/]+)/[^/]+)/?$ /index.php?username=$1&content=$2&type=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^u/([^/]+)/[^/]+)/?$ /index.php?username=$1&content=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^u/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
```

but i am getting the error

> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

What i am trying to acheive is to turn this url

```
http://www.site.com/users/index.php?username=$1&content=$2&type=$3
```

into

```
http://www.site.com/users/username/followers/newest
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing some open parentheses:

```
RewriteRule ^u/([^/]+)/[^/]+)/[^/]+)/?$ /index.php?username=$1&content=$2&type=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^u/([^/]+)/[^/]+)/?$ /index.php?username=$1&content=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^u/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
```

needs to be:

```
# missing "(" here ----v and --v
RewriteRule ^u/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?username=$1&content=$2&type=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^u/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?username=$1&content=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^u/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Also, if you want your URL's to look like `http://www.site.com/users/username/followers/newest`, change the `^u/` in the beginning to `^users/`.

Comment: Haha how strange you was the person who wrote this for me originally. I plan on putting this in the users/ folder, what do i put at the start for that?

Comment: @user1527354 You're right, not sure how they went missing in my other answer (which I've edited). If you want to put this in the `/users/` directory, make sure to remove the `^u/` from the regexp, the leading `/` from the targets, and add a `RewriteBase /users/` above the rules.

Comment: Perfect thankyou. But when i use .htaccess on my website all the .css gets messed up. Have you experienced this before?

Comment: The relative URI base for all you links have changed from `/` (via `/index.php`) to `/u/something/something/something`, so you need to add `<base href="/">` to the header of your pages. Or make you css/js/image/etc links absolute.